# Google Code Jam 2016 : How Can I optimize the Code?

Tags: javascript

> Problem:
>   Bleatrix Trotter the sheep has devised a strategy that helps her fall asleep faster.
>  First, she picks a number N. Then she starts
>   naming N, 2 × N, 3 × N, and so on. Whenever she names a number, she
>   thinks about all of the digits in that number.
>  She keeps track of
>   which digits (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9) she has seen at least
>   once so far as part of any number she has named.
>  Once she has seen
>   each of the ten digits at least once, she will fall asleep.
>           Bleatrix must start with N and must always name (i + 1) × N directly after i × N. For example, suppose that Bleatrix picks N =
>   1692. She would count as follows:
>           N = 1692. Now she has seen the digits 1, 2, 6, and 9.
>           2N = 3384. Now she has seen the digits 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, and 9.
>           3N = 5076. Now she has seen all ten digits, and falls asleep.
>           
> What is the last number that she will name before falling asleep? If   she will count forever, print INSOMNIA instead.

https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/6254486/dashboard

```
Array.prototype.unique = function () {
    return this.filter(function (value, index, self) {
        return self.indexOf(value) === index;
    });
}

var uniqueArr = [];
var Number = 1692;//Any number 


for (i = 1; ; i++) {
    var x = Number * i;
    while (x > 0) {
        uniqueArr.push(x % 10); //Converting number to Digits and pushing them into an array.
        x = Math.floor(x / 10);
    }
    var ar = uniqueArr.unique();
    if (ar.length == 10) {
        console.log(uniqueArr.unique(), Number * i);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct Url : https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/6254486/dashboard

Comment: an obvious optimization would be to use sets: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Answer (score -1):

As long as x is always a positive number* (which is the case here) you could use

```
x = ~~(x / 10)
```

instead of

```
x = Math.floor(x / 10)
```

Which does the same job but is ~5 times faster. Its more an obvious improvement but it optimize the code anyway.

* ~~ is a bitwise operator, which just cuts off everything after the comma. So ~~-6.6 will result -6, but Math.floor(-6.6) gives you a -7. Be carefull here.

Comment: "*Its more an obvious improvement*" - did you mean "It's more a micro-optimisation"?

Comment: I guess a micro-optimisation helped the OP more then non-optimisation-moaning ;)